# Connection to the java client failed after nebulagraph database was restarted

Tags: nebula-graph

Due to slow query, nebula graph was down.

I ran `I ran` enter code here`, and then the connection to the nebulagraph database was lost. The error message is` java.net.SocketException:Broken pipe(Write failed)`.

I would like to ask if this is normal and if it is possible to optimize the client to automatically recognize and reinitialize the connection pool?

The application is `java client :com.vesoft.client-3.3.0` and the connection pool is `com.vesoft.nebula.client.graph.SessionPool`.

Comment: Can you please fix the formatting of your post? You can see [/editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help on how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, the database kernel restarted the application and the current connection will also be invalid. It will be better that we can catch the corresponding exception in the business layer and re-initialize the session pool. In addition session pool and connection pool are two different concepts.